# Getting started with mixture models

Tags: references, mixture-distribution

Can you suggest a source (book, lecture notes, etc) that provides a good introduction to mixture modeling? I would like something that discusses (mixes?) theory and application at the graduate level. If it offers examples from the social sciences, even better.

Comment: My answer lists since resources https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245910/35989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finite mixture models, I would recommend McLachlan and Peel's *Finite Mixture Models*, though it might be a bit dated and not particularly social sciencey.

For a quick intro to get the basic idea and play around in Stata, take a look at [Partha Deb's slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20160910074509/https://www.soph.uab.edu/files/16/deb_slides.pdf) and `fmm` from SSC. Lots of economics examples here, but the halibut length with unobserved gender is a timeless classic.