# How to build a Bayesian regression model of a response that is a Gaussian mixture

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, gaussian-mixture-distribution, stan

**Context:**
My response looks like a mixture model with two classes as you can see on the picture.

[image: density of my response]

I have a couple of predictors that perform relatively well in a linear regression (Bayesian or not). In the Bayesian context I am using MCMC sampling with stan like this:

\begin{align}
\beta \sim {\rm Student}(7, 0, 20)&  \\
\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)&  \\
\sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)&  \\
y|X \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta + \alpha, \sigma)&
\end{align}

where $X$ are my predictors.

Here is an excerpt of the code in `stan`:

```
library(rstanarm)
model.glm <- stan_glm(y~poly(x1,4)+I(x2-x3), data=data, subset=train_index,
                      family=gaussian(link="identity"), prior=student_t(7,0,20),
                      chains=5)
```

As you can imagine, my posterior is going to look like a normal distribution, which is confirmed by this chart:

```
predict <- posterior_predict(model.glm,data[-train_index])
ppc_dens_overlay(data[-train_index]$y,predict[1:300,])
```

[image: prediction]

**Problem:**
I would like my posterior to show the mixture model. However, I am having some issue to model it as I am fairly new to Bayesian stats.

**Question:**
How do you model a mixture model with predictor in MCMC sampling?

**Progress so far:**
I thought that I could use a multinomial prior (it could be binomial for my case but if I can make it generic why not!) with two classes, but then I am not sure where to go from there. This is the start that I tried to model but got stuck.

\begin{align}
\mu \sim {\rm Multinomial}(\tau, \gamma)&  \\
X_j \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma\star)&  \\
Y|X \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \sigma)&
\end{align}

Comment: @gung edited my question. Let me know if it needs further editing.

Comment: This question now seems to me to be on topic here. I am retracting my close vote.

Comment: @gung thumbs up for your edit. I wish I could upvote it.

Comment: You are possibly looking for [latent class regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245902/is-there-any-algorithm-combining-classification-and-regression/245910#245910), but what you are showing us is marginal distribution of $Y$ and regression estimates the conditional distribution of $Y|X$ and it's a different thing.

Comment: @Tim thank you for your help. I think the math might be wrong there.
Really what I am looking for is: How to build a Bayesian regression model of a response that is a Gaussian mixture.
LCR might be it. I honestly didn't know about it. I was hoping to do that in stan but if I get the math right, the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Likelihood

For a mixture of two Gaussians, the likelihood can be written as:
$$
y_i \sim \pi N(y_i|\alpha_0 + x_i\beta, \sigma_0) +  (1-\pi) N(y_i|\alpha_1 + x_i\beta, \sigma_1)
$$
where $\pi \in [0, 1]$.

This is fine, but having two components in the likelihood makes sampling more difficult.  A trick when dealing with mixture models is to augment the model with indicator variables that indicate to which class an observation belongs.  So, for example, $\delta_i=0$ if the observation belongs to the first class, and $\delta_i=1$ if the observation belongs to the second class.  If $p(\delta_i=0)=\pi$, the likelihood could be written as
$$
y_i |\delta_i \sim \left[N(y_i|\alpha_0 + x_i\beta, \sigma_0)\right]^{1-\delta_i}  \times  \left[N(y_i|\alpha_1 + x_i\beta, \sigma_1)\right]^{\delta_i},
$$
and marginalizing out $\delta_i$ would lead to the recovery of the original likelihood.

## Priors

In the model below, $\sigma^2_0$  and $\sigma^2_1$ have reference priors.  Normal priors aren't the best choice for $\sigma^2_0$  and $\sigma^2_1$ because the normal distribution has support on the real line, but the scale parameters can only take on positive values.

Priors:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_0 & \sim N(0, \tau_{\alpha_0}^2) \\
\alpha_1 & \sim N(0, \tau_{\alpha_1}^2) \\
\beta & \propto 1 \\
p(\sigma_0) & \propto \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \\
p(\sigma_1) & \propto \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} \\
\pi & \sim Unif(0, 1) \qquad \text{i.e. } Beta(1, 1).
\end{align*}

## MCMC Sampling

The joint distribution up to a proportionality constant is given by
\begin{align*}
p(\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \beta, \sigma_0^2, \sigma_1^2 | \cdot) \propto & \ \exp\left( \frac{-\alpha_0^2}{2\tau_{\alpha_0}^2} \right) \exp\left( \frac{-\alpha_1^2}{2\tau_{\alpha_1}^2} \right) \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2} \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} \\
& \times \prod_{i=1}^n \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_0^2}} \exp\left( \frac{-(y_i - (\alpha_0 + x_i\beta))^2}{2 \sigma_0^2} \right)\right]^{1-\delta_i} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2}} \exp\left( \frac{-(y_i - (\alpha_1 + x_i\beta))^2}{2 \sigma_1^2} \right)\right]^{\delta_i}
\end{align*}

After some algebra it's possible to find the conditional distributions of the parameters.  In this case, all the full conditionals have closed forms, so a Gibbs sampler can be used to get draws from the joint posterior.

#### Full conditionals

\begin{align*}
\sigma_0^2 | \cdot &\sim IG \left( \frac{n_0}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i|\delta_i=0} \left( y_i - (\alpha_0 + x_i\beta) \right)^2 \right) \\
\sigma_1^2 | \cdot &\sim IG \left( \frac{n_1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i|\delta_i=1} \left( y_i - (\alpha_1 + x_i\beta) \right)^2 \right) \\
\end{align*}
where $i|\delta_i=0$ is used to denote the set of $i$ such that $\delta_i=0$, and $n_0$ is the count of the $\delta_i$ where $\delta_i=0$.  The same type of notation is used for $i|\delta_i=1$ and $n_1$.

Conditional on the $\delta_i$, the posterior distribution for $\beta$ is 
\begin{align*}
\beta | \cdot & \sim N(m, s^2) \\
\text{with} & \\
m & =\left( \sum_{i|\delta_i=0} x_i^2 \sigma_1^2 + \sum_{i|\delta_i=1} x_i^2 \sigma_0^2\right)^{-1} \left( \sigma_1^2 \sum_{i|\delta_i=0}(y_i x_i - \alpha_0 x_i) + \sigma_0^2 \sum_{i|\delta_i=1}(y_i x_i - \alpha_1 x_i) \right) \\
s^2 & = \frac{\sigma_0^2 \sigma_1^2}{\sum_{i|\delta_i=0} x_i^2 \sigma_1^2 + \sum_{i|\delta_i=1} x_i^2 \sigma_0^2}
\end{align*}

The conditional distributions for $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ are also normal
\begin{align*}
\alpha_0 & \sim N\left((\sigma_0^2 + n_0 \tau_0^2)^{-1} \tau_0^2 \sum_{i|\delta_i=0}(y_i - x_i \beta), \, \frac{\tau_0^2 \sigma_0^2}{\sigma_0^2 + n_0 \tau_0^2} \right) \\
\alpha_1 & \sim N\left((\sigma_1^2 + n_1 \tau_1^2)^{-1} \tau_1^2 \sum_{i|\delta_i=1}(y_i - x_i \beta), \, \frac{\tau_1^2 \sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 + n_1 \tau_1^2} \right).
\end{align*}

The indicator variables for the class membership also need to be updated.  These are Bernoulli with probabilities proportional to
\begin{align*}
p(\delta_i=0|\cdot) & \propto N(y_i|\alpha_0 + x_i \beta, \, \sigma_0^2) \\
p(\delta_i=1|\cdot) & \propto N(y_i|\alpha_1 + x_i \beta, \, \sigma_1^2). \\
\end{align*}

## Results

The MCMC predictions are bimodal as intended

[image]

Here's the inference on the posterior distributions of the parameters, with the true values shown by the vertical red lines

[image]

## A couple comments

I suspect you know this, but I wanted to emphasize that the model I've shown here only has a single regression coefficient $\beta$ for both classes.  It might not be reasonable to assume that both populations respond to the covariate in the same way.

There are no restrictions on $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ in the prior specification, so in many cases there will be identifiability issues which lead to label switching.  As the MCMC runs, $\alpha_0$ may sometimes be larger than $\alpha_1$, and other times $\alpha_1$ may be larger than $\alpha_0$.  The changing values of $\alpha$ will affect the $\delta_i$, causing them to swap labels from 0 to 1 and vice versa.  These identifiability issues aren't a problem as long as your interest is only in the posterior predictive or inference on $\beta$.  Otherwise changes may need to made in the prior, for example by forcing $\alpha_0 \leq \alpha_1$.

I hope this is helpful.  I included the code I used.  I believe this can be done in Stan easily as well, but I haven't used Stan in a while so I'm not sure.  If I have time later I may look into it.

## Edit: Results using Stan

I added some code for a similar model using Stan in case that is useful.  Here's the same plot using the Stan model:

[image]

```r
set.seed(101)

library(rstan)

# Simulation truth --------------------------------------------------------
beta.tr <- 1.5
alpha.0.tr <- 2.0
alpha.1.tr <- -3.0
sigma.2.0.tr <- 0.5
sigma.2.1.tr <- 0.1
n.obs <- 200
class.proportion <- 0.3 # 30% in one component, 70% in the other
delta.vec.tr <- rbinom(n.obs, size=1, prob=class.proportion)

y.obs <- vector(length=n.obs)
x.obs <- runif(n.obs, -1, 1)
for(i in 1:n.obs) {
    if(delta.vec.tr[i]==0) {
        y.obs[i] <- rnorm(1, alpha.0.tr + x.obs[i]*beta.tr, sqrt(sigma.2.0.tr))
    }
    else {
        y.obs[i] <- rnorm(1, alpha.1.tr + x.obs[i]*beta.tr, sqrt(sigma.2.1.tr))
    }
}

# Priors ------------------------------------------------------------------
tau.2.alpha0 <- 30
tau.2.alpha1 <- 30

# Samplers ----------------------------------------------------------------
x.obs.sqrd <- x.obs^2
y.times.x <- y.obs*x.obs

fn.sample.beta <- function(alpha.0, alpha.1, sigma.2.0, sigma.2.1, delta.vec) {
    sd.2.denom <- sum(delta.vec*x.obs.sqrd*sigma.2.1 + delta.vec*x.obs.sqrd*sigma.2.0)
    sd.2.num <- sigma.2.0*sigma.2.1
    sd.2 <- sd.2.num/sd.2.denom
    mu <- (1/sd.2.denom)*sum(sigma.2.1*delta.vec*(y.times.x - alpha.0*x.obs) +
                  sigma.2.0*delta.vec*(y.times.x - alpha.1*x.obs))

    return(rnorm(1, mu, sqrt(sd.2)))
}

fn.sample.alpha <- function(beta, sigma.2, delta.vec, tau.2, class.idx) {
    n.members <- sum(delta.vec==class.idx)
    mu <- 1/(sigma.2+n.members*tau.2)*tau.2*sum((delta.vec==class.idx)*(y.obs - x.obs*beta))
    sd.2 <- (tau.2*sigma.2)/(sigma.2 + n.members*tau.2)

    return(rnorm(1, mu, sqrt(sd.2)))
}

fn.sample.sigma <- function(beta, alpha, delta.vec, class.idx) {
    n.members <- sum(delta.vec==class.idx)
    shape <- n.members/2
    rate <- (1/2)*sum((delta.vec==class.idx)*(y.obs - (alpha + x.obs*beta))^2)

    return(1/rgamma(1, shape, rate)) # Inverse-gamma
}

fn.sample.delta <- function(beta, alpha.0, alpha.1, sigma.2.0, sigma.2.1) {
    d0 <- dnorm(y.obs, alpha.0 + x.obs*beta, sqrt(sigma.2.0))
    d1 <- dnorm(y.obs, alpha.1 + x.obs*beta, sqrt(sigma.2.1))
    prob.1 <- d1/(d0 + d1)

    return(rbinom(n.obs, size=1, prob=prob.1))
}

# MCMC --------------------------------------------------------------------
n.samples <- 20000
posterior.draws <- matrix(nrow=n.samples, ncol=5)
colnames(posterior.draws) <- c("beta", "alpha.0", "alpha.1", "sigma.2.0", "sigma.2.1")
delta.draws <- matrix(nrow=n.samples, ncol=n.obs)
y.rep <- matrix(nrow=n.samples, ncol=n.obs)
pi.draws <- vector(length=n.samples)

# Initialization
alpha.0 <- 0
alpha.1 <- 0
sigma.2.0 <- 1
sigma.2.1 <- 1
delta.vec <- as.numeric(y.obs < mean(y.obs))
for(b in 1:n.samples) {
    beta <- fn.sample.beta(alpha.0, alpha.1, sigma.2.0, sigma.2.1, delta.vec)
    alpha.0 <- fn.sample.alpha(beta, sigma.2.0, delta.vec, tau.2.alpha0, class.idx=0)
    alpha.1 <- fn.sample.alpha(beta, sigma.2.1, delta.vec, tau.2.alpha1, class.idx=1)
    sigma.2.0 <- fn.sample.sigma(beta, alpha.0, delta.vec, class.idx=0)
    sigma.2.1 <- fn.sample.sigma(beta, alpha.1, delta.vec, class.idx=1)
    delta.vec <- fn.sample.delta(beta, alpha.0, alpha.1, sigma.2.0, sigma.2.1)

    delta.draws[b,] <- delta.vec
    posterior.draws[b,] <- c(beta, alpha.0, alpha.1, sigma.2.0, sigma.2.1)

    # Posterior predictive
    for(i in 1:n.obs) {
        pi.prob <- rbeta(1, 1 + sum(delta.vec==0), 1 + n.obs - sum(delta.vec==0))
        pi.draws[b] <- pi.prob
        if(runif(1) < pi.prob) {
            y.rep[b, i] <- rnorm(1, alpha.0 + x.obs[i]*beta, sqrt(sigma.2.0))
        }
        else {
            y.rep[b, i] <- rnorm(1, alpha.1 + x.obs[i]*beta, sqrt(sigma.2.1))
        }
    }
}

n.params <- ncol(posterior.draws)
png(file="params.png")
par.orig <- par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
for(i in 1:n.params) {
    param.name <- colnames(posterior.draws)[i]
    plot(density(posterior.draws[,i]), main="", xlab=param.name)
    abline(v=get(paste(param.name, ".tr", sep="")), col="red")
}
par(par.orig)
dev.off()

png(file="postpreds.png")
plot(density(y.obs), xlab="", col="red", ylim=c(0, 0.5), main="", type='n')
for(b in 1:n.samples) {
    lines(density(y.rep[b,]), col=rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.1))
}
lines(density(y.obs), xlab="", col="red", ylim=c(0, 0.5))
legend("topleft", c("y", "y.rep"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1, cex=0.8)
dev.off()


# Stan --------------------------------------------------------------------
model.code <- '
data {
    int<lower=1> K; // number of mixture components
    int<lower=1> N; // number of data points
    real y[N]; // observations
    real x[N]; // covariates
}
parameters {
    simplex[K] pi_prob; // mixing proportions
    real alpha[K]; // locations of mixture components
    real<lower=0> sigma[K];  // scales of mixture components
    real beta; // regression coefficient
}
model {
    real ps[K]; // temp for log component densities
    alpha ~ normal(0, 30);
    for (n in 1:N) {
        for (k in 1:K) {
            ps[k] = log(pi_prob[k]) + normal_lpdf(y[n] | alpha[k] + x[n] * beta, sigma[k]);
        }
    target += log_sum_exp(ps);
    }
}
generated quantities {
    int z; // class index
    real y_rep[N];
    for (i in 1:N) {
        z = categorical_rng(pi_prob);
        y_rep[i] = normal_rng(alpha[z] + beta * x[i], sigma[z]);
    }
}'

model.dat <- list(x=x.obs, y=y.obs, N=length(x.obs), K=2)
stan.fit <- stan(model_code=model.code,
                 model_name="gaussian_mixture",
                 data=model.dat,
                 iter=5000,
                 chains=4,
                 thin=1,
                 warmup=2000,
                 seed=101)
y.rep.stan <- extract(stan.fit)$y_rep
png(file="postpreds_stan.png")
plot(density(y.obs), xlab="", col="red", ylim=c(0, 0.5), main="", type='n')
for(b in 1:nrow(y.rep.stan)) {
    lines(density(y.rep.stan[b,]), col=rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.1))
}
lines(density(y.obs), xlab="", col="red", ylim=c(0, 0.5))
legend("topleft", c("y", "y.rep.stan"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1, cex=0.8)
dev.off()
```

Comment: awesome! Some quicks note:
1. why did you take π∼Unif(0,1)?
2. In your stan code, your sigma is uniform (since you did not specify it). However, in your explaination it was sigma∼N(0,τ2α0). Any reason?
3. Why no prior on Beta?
4. you can easily change your code to have more than one predictor by change X to a matrix[N,NbrPred], vector[NbrPred] beta and it should run.

Comment: Ah, yes good catch.  The Stan model and the other model are similar but not identical.  I didn't really have any special reason for choosing a uniform prior for $\pi$.  Mostly it just seemed convenient.  Same sort of reason for the $\beta$ prior -- basically it was just because I didn't want to do the calculations.  There is no reason you couldn't have one though.  Thanks for the tip about Stan!  I am still a Stan novice.

Comment: I also advise you to look at `library(bayesplot)` that easily allow you to do nice plots (such as the one I made in the question).