# Checking normality from residual plot

Tags: regression, data-visualization, linear-model, residuals, normality-assumption

On fitting a simple linear regression to some data, we get the following residual plot. [image]

Can we say from the inspection of this plot that the normality assumption is violated? What mechanism could have resulted in a plot of this form?

Comment: Although -- with good reason -- this plot is often recommended, I find that people who struggle with it may be helped by also looking at a plot of observed versus fitted. It's the same information but may help to see what is going on. Here two clusters will be either side of the reference line observed $=$ fitted.

Comment: Is this real data? I am wondering if it was invented to make a point. What are the variables and what was your source?

Comment: @Nick Real-world data can look like this: it's a (clear) indication of the presence of a latent binary variable that is strongly associated with the response.

Comment: I agree that such data are entirely possible: it's just that the example is so blatant. There seem to be 20 points on each side too....

Answer (score 3):

The residuals as you've plotted them are *certainly not normal* because they appear to be bimodal.

One possible explanation is that you have omitted a variable in your regression which has an additive effect on the conditional mean.  Let $z$ be a binary indicator for some class membership.  It appears that the true data generating process may look like

$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2z $$

But you've only fit a model with $x$ and not $z$.  I can recreate your plot by simulating this scenario quite easily

```
set.seed(1992)
N = 50
x = rnorm(N)
z = rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
y = x + 2*z + rnorm(N, 0, 0.1)
model = lm(y~x)


plot(fitted(model), resid(model))
```

[image]

Have you omited a variable in your regression? If not, you may find techniques described in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389545/what-if-my-linear-regression-data-contains-several-co-mingled-linear-relationshi/389556#389556) thread interesting.

Comment: Quite insightful! But it seems that I have taken all variables into account in my regression analysis. Is there any other model which can lead to such a residual plot?

Comment: @MathsFreak There might be some variable which was not recorded that is leading to this.  I recommend you use methods in this thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389545/what-if-my-linear-regression-data-contains-several-co-mingled-linear-relationshi/389556#389556