# Simultanously fitting multiple regression models on one dataset

Tags: regression, categorical-data

Suppose there are two groups of (x, y) pairs, and that `x` and `y` are linearly correlated but with different slopes and/or intercepts for different groups.

We do not know which data point belongs to which group a priori, but we know that there are two groups.

I am looking for a method to fit simultaneously two linear models, such that the groups are automatically detected and models fitted. For a given x value, there will be two y-values predicted for both groups, I cannot implement with a GLM, as putting side-by-side the two design matrices, I would get collinear columns, which would break the fitting process. Appreciate any hints.

Comment: I would look into the `flexmix` R package for mixture models

Comment: Already answered here.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245902/is-there-any-algorithm-combining-classification-and-regression/245910#245910